# Coordinating Multiple Sprite Animations in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, ios, animation, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have a 5 frame run animation for a character on a sprite sheet.  I would like to give this character multiple "upgrades", such as sunglasses, hats, etc.  I don't know the "correct way" to do this, so here's what I did:

I constructed a layer to represent the sprite itself, and added the character first, then the hat on top.  I have a 5 frame animation for where the hat would be on that characters head ALSO on the sprite sheet, and have it animating with the exact same parameters as the main character.

The problem is that when I try to animate the two sprites simultaneously (the character sprite and the hat sprite), they get out of sync.  Sometimes it works great, but sometimes the timing is just a wee bit off, which is enough that his head will go through the top of the hat, or the hat will pop off his head every step.

My current solution is to have an update tick, and manually cycle through the frames every time some number of milliseconds has passed, which works, but I assume since I'm manually setting the frames it's using up more processor time than needed.

So what would be the "correct" way to add a hat to a sprite without having to have a "hatted sprite" series on your sprite sheet, and keep them animating together.

edit: sorry this is tagged badly, I apparently don't have a high enough reputation to tag this "cocos2dx", despite the fact that it's a cocos2dx question.

Comment: is the `hat` sprite a child of the `character`

Comment: No, both the character sprite and the hat sprite are added to a blank "class MovingObjects : public Layer { }" declared in my .h file, which is then added to the scene.  When triggering 2 simultaneous animations on each sprite, they don't come out synchronous, so right now I'm setting a variable "_timeToTriggerNextFrame" and when getTimeTick() exceeds that, i manually am setting the frame for each, based on incrementing a "_currentRunFrame++" variable, and using setSpriteFrame to set the next frame manually for each.  Its functional but probably there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Well if i have the same situation i will go with taking different spritesheets for different animation according to upgrade of character, that way there will be no need for two different animation pluse u can adjust sprites for best effect and it won't interfare with other animation, only problem is u have to make different sprites according to upgrade.

Comment: Viper, thanks for the suggestion!  If we had only 1 or 2 linear upgrades that would be a good solution, but if we're talking 10 possible helmets, 10 armors, 10 pants, 10 gloves, and 10 boots, we're talking 100,000 sprite sheets, and if I want to change the color of the characters hair, I need to redo all 100,000 sprite sheets.  There must be a way to animate a character made up of multiple parts and keep them synchronized.

Comment: If there are too many sprite as said than go for Skeleton animation using Spine(Paid), Create animation using spine and export it to use in your project, you will get  .png file, .json file and a .atlas file use them for character animation, best part is you can have multiple animation in a single animation file and you can call them by name, and animation is far more smooth than sprite animation. I have use it in my game where i have to perform walk and attack animations, its worth giving a try.You can see example in testCpp. let me know if that work out for you.

Comment: Not that I'm against throwing money at it, but I feel like this is shooting a mosquito with a shotgun...  There needs to be a simple solution, as I've seen these types of things done in all sorts of games dating back to Super Nintendo.  When characters pick up one of a million in-game swords, how do they attach it to the hand?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of animation are you using?

I recommend you to animate using an skeleton. This way is very easy to replace any body-part with different sprites. In TestCpp you have some examples of skeleton animation using CocoStudio (free) or Spine (paid). You even have an example of an animation where weapons are replaced.

If you need to stick to standard frame animation, you need to make sure that both animations start from the same frame when you replace anything. Otherwise, if you replace your hat when you are on a keyframe different from 0, the animation will be out of sync. One solution is to restart both animations. The other is to check the current frame of the body animation and force the hat animation to start on that frame.

Comment: i was under the impression that skeleton animations were mostly for 3d stuff and far more complicated to assemble.  I'm trying to animate hand-drawn sprites and add accessories

Comment: I could add, if anyone is familiar with Terraria, it's a good example.  It runs as a basic 2 frame sprite, but there are dozens of power ups and weapons and such.

Comment: 2D or 3D is the same, just with 1 dimension less, so easier! As I explained, one of the biggest benefits of skeletal animation is that a single static sprite is assigned and animated via bones. That allows to easily replace sprites and also reduces A LOT the memory (and size) of your game. If you stick to traditional frame animation, you will need to create syncronized animations for every single piece of cloth you want to add.

Comment: i'm fine with synchronized animations, the question originally was HOW to synchronize animations.  Is it enough to simply start 2 animations at exactly the same time?

Comment: If both you animations are properly done and have the same number of frames (as they should), you can update both animations at the same time using just the same "_currentRunFrame".

Answer (score 1):

OK so what I ended up doing, all the sprites that are assembling a larger character object are put together in a class, together with a float "_lastFrameUpdateTick" and int "_lastFrameNumber".  in my update(dt) I have a switch case on _lastFrameNumber for each sprite so it knows if the current time tick is past the _lastFrameUpdateTick + that frame's display time, it should update all the sprites in that class to the next frame number (also allowing me to shift around sprites relative position manually, for cases where, say, a character is bouncing up and down on the back of a horse).  This does require me to put copies of any hats repeatedly on the sprite sheet for every animation (though that could probably be faked with plist were one so inclined).  This also has the added advantage of allowing certain frames to display slightly longer or shorter than others, allow explicit skipping around in animation sequences depending on events (if there's an earthquake and the character is on a leaned-back part of an animation it falls backwards; if it's on the leaned forward frame of an animation it falls forward), and its easy to halt animations while allowing other stuff to keep running.  Most importantly is that doing it manually allows me to always know exactly what frame a sprite is on, so it can smoothly transition between animations without hiccups (I know that if i'm leaned back and want to run forward, i need to go through a leaning-forward animation first).

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but I'm no C++ developer, and it works, so I'm moving on.